# typescript does not detect the type was narrowed

Tags: typescript

```
function encodeToken(value: number | string | null | undefined) {
  if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
    value = value.toString()
  }

  return encodeBase64(value) // typescript complains this line
}

function encodeBase64(value: string | null | undefined) { ... }
```

Typescript complains as below:

> (parameter) value: string | number
> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

---

The "value" which I passed to `encodeBase64` would be `string | null | undefined`, any `number` value will transform to `string`,

Does anyone know how to fix it? Very appreciated

Comment: Which version are you using? It works fine in version 4.7.4

Comment: I use the version 4.5.4

Comment: Using the playground, even with 4.4.4, I can't reproduce the issue https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAU0nAJsgKnA1qgCgDcBDAGxGQC5EwQBbAI2QCdEAfRAZyhZjADmHWiDJlh4TMH7J0ASkQBvAFCJEMYImLlKiAIQBeAyLGIAZGcSkKyfUcSTk0sLIUq1a67uNfkAOig4AGVefgECOVVEAF9lKJZkKBAWJFQIDGQAIRIuZAA2ABZtGwUAelLEKABPAAdkLgg+GqhEdPoashJ+LkqACxgeshllWOVQSFgEFDRMbNzC4soaHj5BYTpTTkdnVyVEBKSUxAAiLjh6RP7BY4BuGOUgA

Comment: Thanks, I use typescript with Nestjs, it's installed as a dependency, I can not upgrade the version easily

Comment: I found that the problem can be reproduced when I disable `"strictNullChecks"` in tsconfig, and gone when I re-enable it.

Comment: And (if "strictNullChecks" is disabled) if you put the statement outside the "if", then it won't complain (successfully narrowed down). Looks like TS will skip the some checks within `if(value! ==null && value!== undefined)` when the "strictNullChecks" is false.

Comment: @qrsngky Thank you very much, your comment is the acceptable answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when `"strictNullChecks"` is false in tsconfig.

Without the 'if' statement, this is ok:

```
function encodeToken(value: number | string | null | undefined) {
  value = value.toString() //narrowed down from `number | string` to `string` after this line
  return encodeBase64(value) 
}
```

But this does not work:

```
function encodeToken(value: number | string | null | undefined) {
  if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
    value = value.toString()
  }
  return encodeBase64(value) //value is still considered `number | string`, so it complains
}
```

Apparently, TS skipped some checking for the `if (value !== null && value !== undefined)` part when "strictNullChecks" is false.

If you change "strictNullChecks" to true, the complaint disappears (the type is correctly narrowed down from `number | string | null | undefined` to `string | null | undefined`).